# Problem changing the value of a checkbox dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a checkbox on a form which works fine. When the form s clicked I am trying to change the value to 1, when not clicked the value should be zero. I am filling the field dynamically using JavaScript. The problem is, when I log it in console I get an empty value..

**Checkbox field**

```js
function checkMark() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("spouse");

  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    checkBox.value = '1';
  } else {
    checkBox.value = 'O';
  }
}

var spouse = $('#spouse').val();
console.log(spouse);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="spouse" value="" class="spouse" onclick="checkMark()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of your issue is that you're *logging* just when the page is initially loaded. You have to *log* the result every time you change the `checkbox` value.

Also, you can use `ternary` operator in order to simplify the solution.

```js
function checkMark() {
     var checkBox = document.getElementById("spouse");
     checkBox.value = checkBox.checked ? '1' : '0';
     log();
}

function log(){
     var spouse = $('#spouse').val();
     console.log(spouse);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="spouse" value="" class="spouse" onclick="checkMark()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your function over onChange instead of onClick